# Display partial screen on projector

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, adobe-photoshop, projector

For a musical, live-drawing (in Photoshop or other sofware) will be projected onto the stage background. However, I do not want to display the toolbars and chrome.

Is there a way to only project a part of the main computer screen?

The projector is attached to the ceiling of the theater, so physical clipping would be arduous.

Comment: I assumed you're using Windows. If not, please add more details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a silly suggestion but you can use powerpoint?  Draw on an empty slide and when you run the presentation it will run full screen.  You can use basic drawing tools on the empty slide during the musical.